# Stationary wavelet transform in C# (ReverseBior)

Tags: c#

I'm writing to ask a question regarding the implementation of stationary wavelet transform in c sharp. first of all, I tried to use the swt function in Matlab by using "ReverseBior" wavelet and it works, but now I want to use C# for some reasons.

I found the swt library on Github[1](https://github.com/maheshkha/Stationary-wavelet-transform-csharp/tree/master/testswt/testswt/bin)

Unfortunately, I'm a beginner in C# coding and I don't have any ideas about the "ReverseBior" wavelet library. therefore, I would be grateful if someone elaborates on how to find the "ReverseBior" library in C#.

Comment: There is no guarantee that there *is* such a library for c#, but a good place to start would be the Math .Net library. However, questions for libraries should go to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: maybe you can call matlab library from C# like it https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html